# R: remove columns based on row value

Tags: r, data.table

did some research but was unable to find a straight answer for my simple problem.
I have a data table like this:

```
var1<-sample(12:43,5,replace=T)
var2<-sample(5:20,5,replace=T)
var3<-rep(0, 5)
var4<-sample(2:6,5,replace=T)
var5<-rep(0,5)
df<-data.table(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)

     var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1:   36   14    0    2    0
2:   43   19    0    6    0
3:   20    6    0    6    0
4:   41   17    0    2    0
5:   32    8    0    6    0
```

I want to remove all columns containing only 0 values. 
This will generate a logical vector.

```
a<-df[,(df[20,]) != 0]
```

How can I use my logical vector to subset the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need the data.table methods, loop through the Subset of data.table (`lapply(.SD`), check whether `all` the values are 0, `unlist` the output, negate (`!`) and subset the columns based on the logical index.

```
 df[, df[, !unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) all(x==0)))], with = FALSE]
```

Or using `base R`, we can `Filter` the columns where the `var` or `sum` is not 0.

```
 Filter(var, df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```r
var1<-sample(12:43,5,replace=T)
var2<-sample(5:20,5,replace=T)
var3<-rep(0, 5)
var4<-sample(2:6,5,replace=T)
var5<-rep(0,5)
df<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)

library(dplyr)
# keep only columns for which all line are different from 0
df %>% select_if(function(col) !all(col == 0))
#>   var1 var2 var4
#> 1   13   20    4
#> 2   39   19    6
#> 3   14   20    2
#> 4   35   13    3
#> 5   35   17    4
```

Comment: It also works, but this will delete columns for which some values are 0 and some are not. I would rather remove only columns containing all 0 values.